# Debuging VBScript in Visual Studios Express

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, wsh

I have read around the net that its possible to debug VBScript WSH files Visual Studios 2005 Express (I think Web Edition) but everytime I try cscript.exe myscript.vbs //X the script just executes.

I have tried VS Express 2005, 2008 and 2010 all editions.

I have also tried Visual Studios Premium 2010 which does infact debug scripts as I would expect however I want to be able to debug scripts with free tools (I don't want to get a VS 2010 licence for all the other people on my team).

I know about Microsoft Script Debugger but it doesn't let you discover objects as well as Visual studios does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you insert your vbscript into a [wsf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file, you can use the `<?job debug="true" error="true" ?>` processing instruction which will generate a dialog that gives you an option to select a debugging engine from a list which should include all versions of VS you have installed, plus the Script Debugger and the Debugger that comes with Office

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. I have tried it on both my home machine and work machine. Both running Windows 7. They both just ignore the statment and excute the script.

Comment: actually, I wrote this answer after using XP at work. I've just tried running a test script on Vista with the `<?job ?>` line, the `Stop` and `debugger` commands and the `//d` and `//x` options for wscript and none work at all.

Comment: in vista at least, you may need to run the script as Administrator to get the debugging rights http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/011de1dc-5cf8-46ba-b8ef-21c3f414e80a/